# User login validation with node/ejs/express/mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am attempting to make a login page that both validates the username and password as well as redirect to another page if the username and password are correct.  However, the error message for incorrect login credentials does not render to the login page, and the page does not change if the login is correct (should redirect to 'home').  The console.log messages do show for the server side code, and I did log the 'item' to check that the findOne found the username if it existed (and that worked).

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id='loginTable'>
    <form action='/login' method='POST' id='loginForm'>
            <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type='text' name='loginUname' id='loginUname'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='loginPword' id='loginPword'></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><% if (lerr) { %>Incorrect username/password combo<% } %></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' id='loginSite' value='Login' onclick='loginUser();'></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Here is my client side code:

```
function loginUser() {
    var loginQuery = {
        loginUname: document.getElementById('loginUname').value,
        loginPword: document.getElementById('loginPword').value
    };

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", '/login', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.send(JSON.stringify(loginQuery));
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is my server side node code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var parser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var app = express();

//... rest of code

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { lerr: false });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {     
    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        // Look for username
        db.collection('users').findOne({
            username: req.body.loginUname,
        }, function(err, item) {
            if (err) return res.send();

            // If the username is not found or the login password doesn't match the user's password
            if (!item) {
                console.log("The username is not valid\n");
                res.render('login', { lerr: true });
            } else {
                if (req.body.loginPword !== item.password) {
                    console.log("The password is not correct\n");
                    res.render('login', { lerr: true });
                } else {
                    console.log("The entry is correct!\n");
                    res.redirect('/home');
                }
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `if (err) return res.send();` is not sending anything. Do `if (err) return res.send({lerr: false});`.

Comment: That actually didn't work, the error message doesn't render then either.

Comment: If there is an error, can you check printing something in console works or not?

Comment: I just put a console.log in for the if (err), and the error message doesn't display regardless if the username or password is incorrect: if (err) {
                                console.log("Error");
                                return res.send({lerr: false});
                        }

Comment: I was doing this in Chrome the whole time, and just switched to Firefox, now everything's working, not sure what's with that.